# JQuery: get object inside span

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am very new to jQuery. Below is part of my code

```
<div class = 'buttons'>
    <span>
    <input type='button' value='BUTTON1' id='button1'>
    </span>
    <span>
    <input type='button' value='BUTTON2' id='button2'>
    </span>
</div>
```

Using jquery, I would like to print the id of the button clicked. I tried the following:

```
$(".buttons > span").click(function () {
    alert("YOU CLICKED" + this.id);
});
```

But I think this is referring to the span object. This is weird because how come the span object has a click event? Or all jquery objects have "click"? 
How do I get the id of the button in the span?

Thank You.

Comment: Almost all DOM elements allow for mouse events handling. If you bind the handler to a `span` element, `this` will reference the DOM element which triggered the event handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this?

```
$(".buttons > span > input").click(function () {
    alert("YOU CLICKED" + this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to do that by capturing the event's target element:

```
$(".buttons > span").click(function (e) { 
    alert("YOU CLICKED" + e.target.id); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".buttons > span").click(function () {
    alert("YOU CLICKED" + $('input[type=button]',this).prop('id'));
 });
```

or you could bind the event to the button itself

```
$(".buttons > span > input[type=button]").click(function () {
    alert("YOU CLICKED" + this.id);
 });
```

Comment: What does the comma do? $('input[type=button]',this)

Comment: @SquallLeohart the comma separates parameters, anyway the second parameter is the context to search by, normally its the document root but if you specify a context the search is performed from that element. So `$('input[type=button]',this)` means select all  inputs of type button that are descendants of `this` element. see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: It selects ALL inputs of type button? Then how does it know which button I clicked to print out the ID?

Comment: @SquallLeohart you forgot the `that are descendants of this element`, `this` represents the span which was clicked and it has only one inputs of type button descendant.